# React SSR with nested Mobx stores

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, mobx, mobx-react

It is possible make ssr app with nested mobx stores? Problem is how serialize root store and restore it?

Example of my stores:

```
export default class RootStore {
     session = new SessionStore(this);
     ui = new UIStore();
}

export default class SessionStore {
    serverActionChecking = new ActionStore(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the process of rendering content on the server, and then **hydrating** the same stores in the frontend (like Next.js), you could do something like this:

You could have a special function that creates your `root` store and depending on if the function is called **with** or **without** data, it calls the root store `hydration` method. Then the root store, after instantiation of the child stores, calls their `hydration` methods. Hydration data should be an object that has keys that correspond to the child stores, so you could just pass specific keys to specific stores.

```js
function initializeStore(initialData ) {
  const store = new RootStore();

  if (initialData) {
    store.hydrate(initialData);
  }

  return store;
}


class RootStore {
  hydrate(data) {
    if(data.childStoreOne){
      this.childStoreOne.hydrate(data.childStoreOne);
    }
  }
}

class ChildStoreOne{
  hydrate(data){
    //do something with the data
  }
}
```

Now all that is left to do is to get the `hydration` data to the browser. One of the solutions is to embed the data in the `script` tag and pass it to the `initialization` function.